# 2 Views in one UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I need to know just how to achieve the purpose of the image below (Contact info view and Inquiry view) any suggestion will be great even without writing code.

the image:

[image]

Comment: on button tap, hide/show or add/remove views accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place two views with identical frame in one viewcontroller and make
   on of them hidden. When user switch Contact Info to Enquiry then
   make hidden another view, just change hidden property for views.
2. If those views is a UITableView then use one UITableView with
   different datasources and change logic into UITableView delegate
   methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just below your button controller put two view overlapping each other and once a tap s received show the one and hide the other... its pretty simple actually hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
self.contactInfoView = [[UIView alloc]init];//whatever you need
self.enquiryView = [[UIView alloc]init];//same here, do whatever you need
//customize you views
UIButton *contactInfoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIButton *enquiryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//customize the buttons
[contactInfoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showContactView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[enquiryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showEnquiryView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then make 2 methods to show the views. Can be simple like:

```
-(void)showContactView {
  self.enquiryView.hidden = YES;
  self.contactInfoView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Hope it helps